# Can't get object attribute in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube

I have following problem that I can't figure out.
I a homepage on my WP blog that contains some youtube videos. 
My task is to get all youtube URLs from youtube objects on the page.

So I did something like this:

```
jQuery("object").each(function() {
  $ytbURL = jQuery(this).find("embed").attr("src");
  $ytbID = $ytbURL.match(...); //here I got error from IE8 that ytbURLis null or not and object
});
```

On FF it works flawlessly.

Update 15/12:
Here are the code samples.

**IE8 - Developer tools:**

```
<OBJECT codeBase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" classid=clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000 width=320 height=267><PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="8466"><PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="7064"><PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0"><PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0"><PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Transparent"><PARAM NAME="Play" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="Loop" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High"><PARAM NAME="SAlign" VALUE="LT"><PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Base" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="Scale" VALUE="NoScale"><PARAM NAME="DeviceFont" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="EmbedMovie" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="BGColor" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="SWRemote" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="MovieData" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="SeamlessTabbing" VALUE="1"><PARAM NAME="Profile" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="ProfileAddress" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="ProfilePort" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all"><PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreen" VALUE="true">
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="267" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent"></embed></OBJECT>
```

**Wordpress:**

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="320" height="267" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" /><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="267" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent"></embed></object>
```

Looks like IE8 does some changes to source HTML or maybe it's the way how Developer Tools displays it?

Thanx

Sam

Comment: Thanx mu, I'm not sure what version I have, becase I'm using jQuery that Wordpress 3.0.1 came with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using jQuery's awesome `$` function instead of `jQuery`, and see if it works:

```
$('object').each(function()
{
  $ytbURL = $(this).find('embed').attr('src');
  $ytbID = $ytbURL.match(...);
});
```

I doubt there would be a difference, but it might work. Oh, and here's a really useful YouTube video ID grabber regex, just in case you need it: `(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+`.

Good luck!

---

Try this. Also, could you give us an example of the DOM jQuery is parsing? It could be because there are multiple `<embed>` tags, so `jQuery(this).find('embed')` would return an array, not a single object.

```
jQuery('object').each(function()
{
  $ytbURL = jQuery(this).children('embed:eq(0)').attr('src');
  $ytbID = $ytbURL.match(...);
});
```

Comment: Um, `$` and `jQuery` are just two names for the same thing. The `jQuery` version is around because some other libraries use `$` and jQuery needs a way to play nice in the namespace.

Comment: Yeah, I just start seeing the `$` as more of a part of JavaScript than a function, so coding with `jQuery()` just throws me off.

Comment: Right, I'm using 'jQuery' instead of '$' because wordpress recomendation to revent conflicts with other libraries. I'm not sure what version I have, becase I'm using jQuery that Wordpress 3.0.1 came with. And thanx for regex Blender. I'm actually using modificated vesion of this ""(.+?)(\/v/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})+" to be able to exctract IDs from that kind of links: "http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0"

Comment: To see your version, run this: `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)`.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried the latest version? That might fix it (it rarely does, but it's worth a shot if nothing else works).

Comment: What would those two things be? Maybe refusing to work with `<embed>` tags is another IE feature ;)

Comment: I actually thiking about two things: 1. IE doesn't like value that attr() returns; 2. attr() actually returns null beause find() can't find nothing. So my questions are: 1. What .attr() shuld return? 2. Maybe the way I'm searching for object parameters is wrong for IE? Maybe there are another way to try search for object params?

Comment: Okay, I've updated my post. Try the code I added last, as it selects the first `<embed>` tag.

Comment: Thanx Blender I going to check it out soon. Anyways here's the code: <object width="320" height="267" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codeBase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" altHtml="<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="267" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TDlqMuGqTyE?fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent"></embed>" style="display: none;">

Comment: I see a big problem! `altHtml="<embed type="application/...` has unescaped double quotes. Either do `altHtml='<embed type="application/...` or `altHtml="<embed type=\"application/...`. This would help debug greatly.

Comment: Wow, now it's the problem, because it's how it stored in Wordress post.looks like WP changes the actuall HTML code...

Comment: Ouch. Is that how the database shows it? If so, than I'm out of ideas. FF displays it normally, but FF swallows as many errors as it can.

Comment: Ok it was my mistake, Wordpress stores it Ok, but IE displays it completely diffrernt. I updated my qestion with code from both sources

Comment: IE escapes the ampersands... I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hey, I just talked with some web development guru and according to him - <embed> tag is not supported in IE, only <OBJECT>. And this is what MS says about the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306790 So I guess I should try get youtube URL using <PARAM> tag.

Comment: Wow, that is ridiculous. It's like IE decided not to implement CSS rules because the Microsoft corporate site doesn't use them. Wow, that makes me cry for those poor IE junkies...

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft being Microsoft, nothing new :)...anyway I figured out how to deal with <object> and <param> tags. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, after we figured out that IE doesn't support `<embed>` tag, the solution was
to search `<param>` tag with source URL inside `<object>`. So here's the code that worked for me:

```
jQuery("object").each(function(){
        var $params = jQuery(this).children('param');
        $params.each(function() {
                if((jQuery(this).attr('name')) == 'src') {
                    $ytbURL = jQuery(this).val();
                    return;
                }
        });

});
```

Use this on your own risk :).
Now I still need to figure out how to autoplay new object, but this is another story :)...

Thanx to all people that helped me on the issue, especially Blender.